# Using WCF  datatypes

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I'm trying to use WCF for the first time however I hit a problem pretty fast that I don't understand. I haven't changed the original structure of the auto generated code yet. I got this code to work on the website.

```
using ServiceReference.ServiceClient wcfClient = new ServiceReference.ServiceClient())
{
  string data = wcfClient.GetData(32);
  Label1.Text += data;
}
```

But when I started using this code I got in to some problem.

```
ServiceReference.Kund kund;

using (ServiceReference.ServiceClient wcfClient = new ServiceReference.ServiceClient())
{
    string data = wcfClient.GetDataUsingDataContract(kund);
}
```

I got the this error. I can't really see any problem with the data type it's not a string.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Webbshop.ServiceReference.Kund' to 'string'

Edit:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);

    [OperationContract]
    Kund GetDataUsingDataContract(Kund kund);
}

[DataContract]
public class Kund
{
    int iD;
    [DataMember]
    public int ID
    {
        get { return iD; }
        set { iD = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show us the service contract (that `IMyService` interface, or whatever it's called in your case) you have??

Typically, the sample apps that the WCF service generates will have one method `GetData` that returns a string, and a second method that shows how to return a complex data type

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);

    [OperationContract]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);
}
```

Here: the second method - after your alterations - returns a `Kund`. Of course, if you call that **second method** which returns a  `Kund`, you cannot just assign your entire  `Kund` to a string.... you would have to do something like:

```
ServiceReference.Kund kund;

using (ServiceReference.ServiceClient wcfClient = new ServiceReference.ServiceClient())
{
    Kund returnedKund = wcfClient.GetDataUsingDataContract(kund);

    // then assign whatever properties from `data` you need to your string .....
    string data = returnedKund.ID.ToString();  // or something.....
}
```

Comment: I only changed the datatype in the interface
    <code>[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        Kund GetDataUsingDataContract(Kund kund);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Kund
    {
        int iD;
        [DataMember]
        public int ID
        {
            get { return iD; }
            set { iD = value; }
        }
    }</code>

Comment: Now I see the problem, I'm trying to asign the return value to the string it's so obvious, I missed it. xD

Comment: @Frozendragon: <hehe> been there, done that - sometimes it's just so blatantly obvious, you just overlook it when trying to figure it out :-) Happens to all of us, I'm pretty sure :-)